# JavaScript Regex: Match exactly N chars, and prevent excessive chars from leaking into capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few strings in this following format:

```
[1985..1989]
[Start..End]
[ 1985 .. 1989 ]
[ Start .. End ]
[ 1985.13579 .. 1989.2468 ]
[ Start.from .. End.at ]
```

And I need to capture the two parts between the brackets and the 2 dots, as well as getting rid of the whitespaces/newlines (eg. `1985` & `1989`). This is the regex I've come up so far:

```
^\[\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\.\.\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\]$
```

(Live tester: http://regex101.com/r/tO8gG6)

---

Now the problem with this regex is that if I have a string which looks like `[2...5]`, the 2nd capturing group will get `.5` which is not what I want (you can check this using the tester above). In such scenario I'd like the match to fail totally, and I'm not sure how to modify the regex above to do that.

Comment: Please provide more example strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a negated class:

```
^\[\s*([^.]+?)\s*\.\.\s*([^.]+?)\s*\]$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fM8pX3)

**EDIT:**

As per your edit, since you can also have periods, you might use this:

```
^\[\s*([^.]+?(?:\.[^.]+?)*?)\s*\.\.\s*([^.]+?(?:\.[^.]+?)*?)\s*\]$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kS2oO5)

Comment: This will leak trailing spaces (if present) into both of the capturing groups; I've updated the question with more example strings.

Comment: @Kay That's fine, you can just turn the greedy `[^.]+` into non greedy `[^.]+?`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important detail which is the capturing part could have dots inside, like 1985.00

Answer (score 1):

Try below, I modified your **\.\.** to **\.+** it means capture all **one or more dots**

```
^\[\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\.+\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\]$
```

I modified your regex http://regex101.com/r/wE6aY0

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important detail which is the capturing part could have dots inside, like 1985.00

Answer (score 0):

EDITED AGAIN!!

Try this **NEW** link:

http://regex101.com/r/vW1wD1

RE RE REVISED EXPRESSION:

```
\[ ?(\d*|\w*)\.?(\d*|\w*) ?.. ?(\d*|\w*)\.?(\d*|\w*) ?\]
```

NOW, it matches all the patterns you have mentioned.

Comment: Updated my answer according to the same.

Answer (score 0):

And here's another contribution that seems to work on what you've provided so far

```
([^\s.[]\S+?)\s*\.{2,}\s*(\S+)\s*\]
```

http://regex101.com/r/bQ1tG9